# How do I update my shopping cart with the product ID using an HTML form?

Tags: python, html, jinja2, flask-sqlalchemy

I am building an e-commerce website with Python, Flask and SQLAlchemy and I am trying to update the quantity of a product on user's cart. I can retrieve the product quantity easily (which is printed on my command line) but I can't get the product ID (which I ultimately need to update my SQL cart table). On the cart page both the quantity and the product ID are properly showing

```
class Products(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(100), nullable=False)
    price = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=False)

@app.route("/cart", methods=["GET", "POST"])
@login_required
def cart():
    cart = Products.query.join(Cart).filter_by(buyer=current_user).all()

    if request.method == "POST":
        qty = request.form.get("qty")
        idpd = request.form.get("idpd")
        print("qty",qty)
        print("id",idpd)


{% for item in cart %}      

<span>
     {{item.name}}
</span>

<div>
    ${{item.price}}
</div>

<form action="{{ url_for('cart') }}" method="post">
<div class="form-group">

 <p name="idpd">{{item.id}}</p>
 <select class="form-control" name="qty">
      <option disabled="Quantity">Qty</option>
      <option>1</option>
      <option>2</option>
      <option>3</option>
 </select>

<button type="submit">
     Update
</button>

{% endfor %}
```

When I select the option 2 for the quantity of the product id 1 and click on Update, I expect the output of qty 2 and id 1 but the actual output is:
qty 2
id None

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make

```
 <p name="idpd">{{item.id}}</p>
```

to

```
<input name="idpd" value="{{item.id}}" hidden>
```